# Windows XP RDP Protocol Error

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I am trying to RDP into a windows xp pro sp3 machine (from windows 7).
The connection is succesfull but after a random amount of time ( usually between 1 and 3 minutes) the **session gets disconnected with the following message**:

```
Protocol Error. Session will be disconnected.
```

I have no idea what is causing this protocol error and apparently it's a very rare error since I couldn't find any useful info on google.
After the session gets disconnected I take  a look at the logs and (every time) under system tab I find 4 new error entries

```
Event 1111 : Driver required for printer ______ is unknown. Contact the administrator to install the driver before you log in again.
```

Could these two things be related?

**What do you think is causing this protocol error?**

Other (possibly) useful info:

- Team viewer is installed on the xp machine (conflict?)
- Rdp port is default 3389

**EDIT**
Disabling printer sharing is not solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the options on the RDP client and disable printer and drive sharing. This is most likely an EasyPrint driver issue

Comment: Sounds very logical! Dodn't think of that. Will try and let you know. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sadly that is not resolving the issue